# Detached and appended textarea loses mouse events

Tags: jquery, append, mouseup

I detached a textarea and appended it to a TD.  It appears to be losing its mouse events after the first resize.

Here's the code:

```
var schedule = $('#daily');
var bar = $('#bar').detach();

function addbar(elem) { 
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.append(bar);
}

schedule.on('click', 'td.d', addbar );
```

To duplicate the issue:

1. Click in a TD.  The textarea is detached and then attached to the
   TD.
2. Resize the textarea.
3. Attempt to resize the textarea a second time. [FAILS]

I also noticed that mouseup events on the textarea did not fire anymore.  I tried to use jquery.off to stop the click-event on the TD, but it did not appear to help the resize issue.

Here's the Codepen:  https://codepen.io/btn-ninja/pen/xNWYpd

Comment: I assume you're testing in Chrome as that displays this behaviour. However Firefox doesn't let you resize the `textarea` at any point after it's added.

Comment: Hadn't even gotten to FF yet.  Ideas?

Comment: It's possible this is a browser issue with the element being dynamically removed from the DOM and then re-attached. While it's theoretically less efficient, I'd suggest trying to append a clone of `bar` in each click event: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwRrVa. The downside is this loses the content and settings of the existing `textarea` on each click, but that can be overcome.

Comment: The clone helped in Chrome but not in any other browser.  Weird.